# WinForms Combobox DataSource Class with sub items

Tags: combobox

I have two classes getting from json request

```
public class User
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class PointUser
{
    public int PointUserId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
    public string notes { get; set; }
}
```

I bind list object of class PointUser to combobox. How can I display sub class User field in my combobox?

```
cmbPointUser.DataSource = ObjListPointUsers;
cmbPointUser.ValueMember = "PointUserId";
cmbPointUser.DisplayMember = "?????"; // fild "name" from sub class User
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1) override the `ToString()` method in the PointUser class and return the sub property User.Name. Do not define the property `DisplayMember`.

2) create a property in the class PointUser and return the sub property User.Name. After that call this property in the `DisplayMember`.